# External Program running in different user desktop

Tags: delphi, pascal, multiple-users

I am trying to execute an external program under `SYSTEM` level and I applied [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760239/create-process-by-system-with-delphi) (where I only changed the `CreateProcessAsSystem('c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe');` to the path of the application I wanted to execute) and it works perfectly as expected only if there is one user logged into the pc.

Eg. I have 2 users (`user1` and `user2`) and both users are logged in (`user1` first and then `user2`). Then, I run the program in `user2` and my external program supposed to appear on `user2`'s desktop. However, it appears on `user1`'s desktop. Can I know what causes this to happen and how can I solve this?

Problem reproduction:

1. Create two users (`user1` and `user2`)
2. Logged in to `user1` first and then `user2`
3. Run the program in `user2`

Code:

TestSystem.pas

```
unit TestSystem;

interface

uses
  Winapi.WinSvc,
  Vcl.SvcMgr,
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.TlHelp32,
  System.Classes;

type
  TTestService = class(TService)
    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
  private
    lpApplicationName,
    lpCommandLine,
    lpCurrentDirectory: PWideChar;
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
  end;

procedure CreateProcessAsSystem(const lpApplicationName: PWideChar;
                              const lpCommandLine:PWideChar = nil;
                              const lpCurrentDirectory: PWideChar  = nil);
var
  TestService: TTestService;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function WTSQueryUserToken(SessionId: ULONG; var phToken: THandle): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Wtsapi32.dll';


type
  TServiceApplicationEx = class(TServiceApplication)
  end;
  TServiceApplicationHelper = class helper for TServiceApplication
  public
    procedure ServicesRegister(Install, Silent: Boolean);
  end;

function IsUserAnAdmin: BOOL; stdcall; external 'shell32.dll' name 'IsUserAnAdmin';

function CreateEnvironmentBlock(var lpEnvironment: Pointer; hToken: THandle;
                                    bInherit: BOOL): BOOL;
                                    stdcall; external 'Userenv.dll';

function DestroyEnvironmentBlock(pEnvironment: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Userenv.dll';


function _GetIntegrityLevel() : DWORD;
type
  PTokenMandatoryLabel = ^TTokenMandatoryLabel;
  TTokenMandatoryLabel = packed record
    Label_ : TSidAndAttributes;
  end;
var
  hToken : THandle;
  cbSize: DWORD;
  pTIL : PTokenMandatoryLabel;
  dwTokenUserLength: DWORD;
begin
  Result := 0;
  dwTokenUserLength := MAXCHAR;
  if OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, hToken) then begin
    pTIL := Pointer(LocalAlloc(0, dwTokenUserLength));
    if pTIL = nil then Exit;
    cbSize := SizeOf(TTokenMandatoryLabel);
    if GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenIntegrityLevel, pTIL, dwTokenUserLength, cbSize) then
      if IsValidSid( (pTIL.Label_).Sid ) then
        Result := GetSidSubAuthority((pTIL.Label_).Sid, GetSidSubAuthorityCount((pTIL.Label_).Sid )^ - 1)^;
    if hToken <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      CloseHandle(hToken);
    LocalFree(Cardinal(pTIL));
  end;
end;

function IsUserAnSystem(): Boolean;
const
  SECURITY_MANDATORY_SYSTEM_RID = $00004000;
begin
  Result := (_GetIntegrityLevel = SECURITY_MANDATORY_SYSTEM_RID);
end;

function StartTheService(Service:TService): Boolean;
var
  SCM: SC_HANDLE;
  ServiceHandle: SC_HANDLE;
begin
  Result:= False;
  SCM:= OpenSCManager(nil, nil, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
  if (SCM <> 0) then begin
    try
      ServiceHandle:= OpenService(SCM, PChar(Service.Name), SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
      if (ServiceHandle <> 0) then begin
        Result := StartService(ServiceHandle, 0, pChar(nil^));
        CloseServiceHandle(ServiceHandle);
      end;
    finally
      CloseServiceHandle(SCM);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure SetServiceName(Service: TService);
begin
  if Assigned(Service) then begin
    Service.DisplayName := 'Run as system service created ' + DateTimeToStr(Now);
    Service.Name        := 'RunAsSystem' + FormatDateTime('ddmmyyyyhhnnss', Now);
  end;
end;

procedure CreateProcessAsSystem(const lpApplicationName: PWideChar;
                              const lpCommandLine:PWideChar = nil;
                              const lpCurrentDirectory: PWideChar  = nil);
begin
  if not ( IsUserAnAdmin ) then begin
    SetLastError(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED);
    Exit();
  end;

  if not ( FileExists(lpApplicationName) ) then begin
    SetLastError(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND);
    Exit();
  end;

  if ( IsUserAnSystem ) then begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TTestService, TestService);
    TestService.lpApplicationName  := lpApplicationName;
    TestService.lpCommandLine      := lpCommandLine;
    TestService.lpCurrentDirectory := lpCurrentDirectory;
    SetServiceName(TestService);
    Application.Run;
  end else begin
    Application.Free;
    Application := TServiceApplicationEx.Create(nil);
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TTestService, TestService);
    SetServiceName(TestService);
    Application.ServicesRegister(True, True);
    try
      StartTheService(TestService);
    finally
      Application.ServicesRegister(False, True);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TServiceApplicationHelper.ServicesRegister(Install, Silent: Boolean);
begin
  RegisterServices(Install, Silent);
end;

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  TestService.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TTestService.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

function ProcessIDFromAppname32( szExeFileName: string ): DWORD;
var
  Snapshot: THandle;
  ProcessEntry: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  Result := 0;
  szExeFileName := UpperCase( szExeFileName );
  Snapshot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if Snapshot <> 0 then
    try
      ProcessEntry.dwSize := Sizeof( ProcessEntry );
      if Process32First( Snapshot, ProcessEntry ) then
        repeat
          if Pos(szExeFileName, UpperCase(ExtractFilename(StrPas(ProcessEntry.szExeFile)))) > 0 then begin
            Result:= ProcessEntry.th32ProcessID;
            break;
          end;
        until not Process32Next( Snapshot, ProcessEntry );
    finally
      CloseHandle( Snapshot );
    end;
end;

function TerminateProcessByID(ProcessID: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
  hProcess : THandle;
begin
  Result := False;
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE,False,ProcessID);
  if hProcess > 0 then
    try
      Result := Win32Check(TerminateProcess(hProcess,0));
    finally
      CloseHandle(hProcess);
    end;
end;

procedure TTestService.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
var
  hToken, hUserToken: THandle;
  StartupInfo : TStartupInfoW;
  ProcessInfo : TProcessInformation;
  P : Pointer;
begin
  if not WTSQueryUserToken(WtsGetActiveConsoleSessionID, hUserToken) then exit;

  if not OpenProcessToken(OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False,
                             ProcessIDFromAppname32('winlogon.exe')),
                             MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,
                             hToken) then exit;

  if CreateEnvironmentBlock(P, hUserToken, True) then begin
    ZeroMemory(@StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
    StartupInfo.lpDesktop := ('winsta0\default');
    StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    if CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, nil, nil, False,
                CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, P, lpCurrentDirectory, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then begin

    end;
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    DestroyEnvironmentBlock(P);
  end;

  CloseHandle(hToken);
  CloseHandle(hUserToken);

  TerminateProcessByID(GetCurrentProcessId);
end;

end.
```

TestProcess.dpr

```
program TestProcess;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.TlHelp32,
  Winapi.Shlobj,
  Winapi.ShellApi,
  TestSystem in 'TestSystem.pas' {TestService: TService};

{$region 'Functions to show process''s thread window'}
function EnumWindowsCallback(Handle: HWND; lParam: Integer): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  WID, PID: Integer;
  Text: PWideChar;
  Placement: TWindowPlacement;
begin
  WID := 0;
  PID := lParam;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(Handle, @WID);
  if (PID = WID) and IsWindowVisible(Handle) then begin
    ShowWindow(Handle, SW_MINIMIZE);
    ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    var test := SetForegroundWindow(Handle);
    OutputDebugString(PWideChar(BoolToStr(test, true)));
    FlashWindow(Handle, True);
    GetWindowText(Handle, Text, 150);
    WriteLn('Window ' + Text + ' showed.');
    Result := False;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

function ShowProcessWindow(PID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsCallback, LPARAM(PID));
end;
{$endregion}

{$region 'Function to kill process'}
procedure KillProcessWithID(PID: Integer);
begin
  var handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, false, PID);
  if handle > 0 then begin
    TerminateProcess(handle, 0);
    CloseHandle(handle);
  end;
end;
{$endregion}

{$region 'Function to search for process using process name'}
function processExists(exeFileName: string; out PID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ContinueLoop: BOOL;
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
  FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  Result := False;
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName)) or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName))) then
    begin
      PID := FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID;
      Result := True;
    end;
    ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;
{$endregion}

var
  ID: Integer;
  Ok: Boolean;
  Input: string;

begin
  try
    repeat
      Write('Enter a process name to check: ');
      ReadLn(Input);
      ID := 0;
      Ok := processExists(Input, ID);

      {$region 'Display process information'}
      WriteLn('');
      WriteLn('Process ' + Input + ' exists --> ' + BoolToStr(Ok, True) + ' --> ' + IntToStr(ID));
      WriteLn('');
      {$endregion}

      {$region 'Show process'}
      if IsUserAnAdmin and (ID > 0) then begin
        WriteLn('Attempt to show process''s thread window...');
        ShowProcessWindow(ID);
      end else if not IsUserAnAdmin then
        WriteLn('Require elevated privilege to show process''s thread window.');
      {$endregion}

      {$region 'Kill process'}
      if (ID > 0) and IsUserAnAdmin then begin
        var reply := '';
        repeat
          Write('Kill process ' + Input + ' (' + IntToStr(ID) + ')? ');
          ReadLn(reply);
        until (reply.ToLower = 'y') or (reply.ToLower = 'n');

        if reply.ToLower = 'y' then KillProcessWithID(ID);
      end else if not IsUserAnAdmin then
        WriteLn('Require elevated privilege to kill process.');
      {$endregion}
    until Input = '';
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Main.dpr

```
program Main;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.IOUtils, TestSystem, Vcl.Forms;

var
  path: string;

begin
  path := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExeName), 'TestProcess.exe');
  CreateProcessAsSystem(PWideChar(path));
end.
```

Comment: maybe you should use CreateProcessAsUser ?

Comment: @Para the code I applied actually using ```CreateProcessAsUser```

Comment: Did you read and understand [Note #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37760827/327083) of the answer in that question?

Comment: @J... yes and I applied those in my code

Comment: This issue is very similar to this question: [Run an external program as admin in a standard user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486674/). Two separate questions with the exact same symptom. Did Microsoft break something recently?

Comment: Can I know why this question is closed?

Comment: @JiaLin Because we cannot solve your problem unless you [edit] the question to include the code you are using, ideally in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: @J... The question is closed after I edited the question....

Comment: And then it looks like you edited it back.  I've reverted the edit to include your code again.

Comment: @J... but the question is still closed... so is there any point to revert the edit?

Comment: @JiaLin as the 'application' is basically a service running as the 'SYSTEM' user, it cannot know which actual user started the service. Therefore, when the 'service' starts the 'desktop' application it just shows it on the first user desktop available...